# Где искать ошибки при возврате страницы page not found

Tags: python, django

Где можно искать ошибки в проекте при возврате страницы page not found (404)?

Comment: `Django` [может](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/error-reporting/#errors) отправить Вам электронное письмо с отладочной информацией в случае 404-ой ошибки.

Comment: А на стадии тестирования Вы можете установить `DEBUG = True` и получить много полезной информации непосредственно на странице.